# PHP rename Permission denied (WAMP)

Tags: php, wamp, rename

Basically,

```
rename("./source", "./$new_name"); //succeeds, 
//but subsequent reversal... 
rename("./$new_name", ./source"); fails...
```

As for why I want to do this hopefully the code in context will explain ...

```
<?php
    //$filename="Simplicity.zip"; (Original Folder)
    //$version ="1.0.4b";
    //End result AM_Simplicity1.0.4b.zip
    $src='source';
    //Destination folder for new Zip file.
    $dst='patched';
    $am_zip = "AM_".rtrim($filename,'.zip');
    $filename = $am_zip.$version.".zip";
    rename("./source", "./$am_zip"); //succeeds
    $src = $am_zip;
    $dst = 'patched';
    include "./recurseZip.php";
    $z=new recurseZip();
    $x = $z->compress($src,$dst,$filename);
    // AND... so that ./source can be emptied on demand later.
    rename("./$am_zip","./source"); //fails... Permission Denied
?>
```

Comment: `./source` is a zip file, right? So why are you renaming it to `X` then back from `X` to `./source`?

Comment: ./source is the contents of a zip file, unzipped and patched.

Comment: Oh so you're renaming a directory with a `.zip` in the end. Ok, my bad.

Comment: Sorry, ./source is the contents of a zip file, unzipped and patched.
The goal being to preserve the unpatched original, create a new zip file in the $dst folder for download via recurseZip(). Needing the ability later to empty the $src and $dst files and patch a different original zip file, I need to rename it back so I'll know the name of the folder to empty.

Comment: Ok, I see, see if my answer helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to see if there is an open file the directory you are renaming? My guess is that the `recurseZip` class is opening a file in `$am_zip` and not closing it properly. And thus, you cannot move/rename it. You could make sure by just putting the 2 `rename` statements right after each other.

Also, the wamp tag suggests you are on Windows, so I guess it isn't really a permission problem. Otherwise, you should make sure you use `chmod` to give write permission to the directories, maybe the `recurseZip` class is not preserving that.

Comment: Good idea Thx!, I'll try stacking them up and see what happens.
And yes, WAMP indicates windows.

Comment: Sure enough! Unpatched the original zips run about 130k
Patched they grow to just over 5MB. Looks like recurseZip kind of chokes on it. I'm thinking maybe something to do with maximum file connections? Grrrr....

Comment: Is the `rescueZip` class [that one](http://ramui.com/articles/php-zip-files-and-directory.html)? Or one you made? If it's the one online, I could try to see if it does the same for me and troubleshoot if you want...

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to sleep(5); before final rename.